# Find max number of items that can fit in a given max-width

Tags: javascript

Given a list of elements, each with own width, and a max-width.
I need to find how many elements can be fit inside that max-width, keeping the order of the elements.

Some examples:

1. elements: { width: 10 }, { width: 20 }
   max-width: 30
   result count should be 2, because both elements can be fit in this max-width
2. elements: { width: 10 }, { width: 20 }
   max-width: 5
   result count should be 0, because first element cannot be fit in this max-width
3. elements: { width: 10 }, { width: 20 }, { width: 5 }
   max-width: 20
   result count should be 1, because adding the second element exceed the max-width.

This piece of javascript code solve it, but I feel it is not readable enough:

```js
function getNumberOfElementsInWidth(elements, maxWidth) { 
  let accWidth = 0;
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    if (accWidth + elements[i].width <= maxWidth) {
      accWidth = accWidth + elements[i].width;
      count++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return count;
}

function doSample() {
  const elements = [ { width: 10 }, { width: 12 }, { width: 15 } ];
  const maxWidth = 100;
  
  console.log(getNumberOfElementsInWidth(elements, maxWidth));
}

doSample();
```

I would appreciate your feedback on how to make the code for `getNumberOfElementsInWidth` function clearer.

Comment: How does `elements: { width: 10 }, { width: 20 }, { width: 5 }` give you result count 1 for `max-width: 20` ?

Comment: @Isac because you can add the first item, but adding the second results in width 30, which is greater than the max-width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Code / algorithm  review.

### Code

- You could have used a for...of loop rather than the standard for loop
- You could have used `return count` rather than breaking out. Some will argue otherwise but I see breaks as disguised gotos and should be avoided. <strike>(In this case your algorithm is buggy so the point is mute)</strike>
- Use the form `n += num` to add rather than `n = n + num`
- Doubling the `accWidth + elements[i].width` addition. Once in the if statement and once if it passes. If you are doubling up on calculations it usually means you can simplify.
- <strike>You have not tested the code vigorously to look for problems</strike>

### Re-write

Using the points above I have written you methods. The test call gives 5 elements, to fit in a 8 units max width. <strike>You result returns the wrong count `3` the count should be `4` elements with widths `1`,`1`,`1`, and `2`</strike>

```js
function countElementsToFillWidth(elements, maxWidth) {
  var accWidth = 0, count = 0;
  for (const {width} of elements) {
    accWidth += width
    if (accWidth > maxWidth) { return count } // could use break if you like
    count ++;
  }
  return count;
}





//=========================================================================
console.log("Find first # items of to fill a width of 8...")
console.log("Solution " + 
  countElementsToFillWidth(
    [{ width: 1}, {width: 2}, {width: 5}, {width: 1}, {width: 1}],
    8
  ) + " items."
);
```

### Algorithm

***UPDATE** seams I miss read the question. The order of the elements must be maintained. I will leave in this second half of my answer in case anyone is interested.*

This is an example of a packing problem. Find the max items to fit a finite space.

Your algorithm assumes that the items to pack are ordered from smallest to highest and thus fails to find better solutions if there are smaller items further in the list.

To fix you need to sort the elements array. This is expensive so to reduce the overhead you can first get the total size of all the items and if they all fit return the element count avoiding the need to sort.

Then if the items width is to large start at the largest and remove  until the you get a length that can fit.

### Improved algorithm

The following solution will find a better count. However I have not come up with a proof that it works for all cases and I feel that there may be some  cases that it may fail, though can not come up with an example (proof false by contradiction).

There is also some ambiguity. Are items with 0 or negative width valid. I have let 0 width items in, but negative items are out, yet could also be valid as they are used to increase the packing size?

```js
function getNumberOfElementsInWidth(elements, maxWidth) { 
    var totalSize = 0;
    elements = elements.filter(element => {
        if (element.width > maxWidth || element.width < 0) { return false }
        totalSize += element.width;
        return true;
    });
    if (totalSize <= maxWidth) { return elements.length }
    elements.sort((a, b) => a.width - b.width);
    count = elements.length;
    while (totalSize > maxWidth) { totalSize -= elements[--count].width   }
    return count;
}





//=========================================================================
// Single test to show correct solution

console.log("Find max items of widths 1, 2, 5, 1, 1 to fit a width of 8")
console.log("Solution " + 
  getNumberOfElementsInWidth(
    [{ width: 1}, {width: 2}, {width: 5}, {width: 1}, {width: 1}],
    8
  ) + " items"
);
```

### Summing up.

You need to ensure that you test as many possible inputs to a function as possible. Don't cherry pick inputs (as you did with the `doSample` function) that you know will work. The aim of testing a function is to find out if you can break it.

Comment: +1, vapid points. One thing, `elements.width > maxWidth && element.width < 0` - shouldn't this be or? Assuming `maxWidth` is positive, it would never pass.

Comment: @Gerrit0 Thanks for the heads up, breaking my own rules by not testing... :(

Comment: @Blindman67 i probably didn't explain myself good enough. The matching should be in order of the elements in the array. not finding the max items that can be fitted. So in your example the answer should be 3, because after adding the first 3 items, I can't add any more without going over max-width. My third example show exactly this case.

Comment: @avivr You can then just ignore the second half of the answer. The First snippet follows your original logic,

Answer (score 1):

I find your code clear enough, but you could improve it a little bit, so you only do the add operation once:

```
function getNumberOfElementsInWidth(elements, maxWidth) {
  let accWidth = 0;
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    accWidth += elements[i].width
    if (accWidth <= maxWidth) {
      count++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

---

Further you could reverse the conditional statement:

```
function getNumberOfElementsInWidth(elements, maxWidth) {
  let accWidth = 0;
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    accWidth += elements[i].width
    if (accWidth > maxWidth) {
      break;
    }

    count++;
  }
  return count;
}
```

---

In a more condensed version you could make the `count` variable also be the `index`:

```
function getNumberOfElementsInWidth(elements, maxWidth) {
  let accWidth = 0;

  for (var count = 0; count < elements.length; count++) {
    if ((accWidth += elements[count].width) > maxWidth) {
      break;
    } 
  }
  return count;
}
```

Be aware that `count` must be declared as `var count = 0` not `let count = 0`

Comment: Instead of adding to `accWidth`, you could subtract from `maxWidth` and compare it to 0. Then you don't even need `accWidth` anymore.